# Maximum concurrent connections on Apache 2.2 running on Windows server 2008 r2 32-bit

Tags: apache, concurrency, windows-server-2008-r2

The stress test I am running makes many connections to my Apache 2.2 running on Windows server 2008 r2 32-bit concurrently. Although my mpm_winnt_module  configuration is:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadsPerChild      1500
MaxRequestsPerChild    0</IfModule>
```

the maximum concurrent connections I can make is 600. I could not find anywhere in Apache 2.2.22 documentation mentioning this.

What is the deal with this? Has 32-bit got to do something with maximum concurrent connections?

Comment: No, 32-bit has nothing to do with the maximum number of concurrent connections.

Comment: Any ideas what it could be?